# Use bottom AND top actionbar

Tags: android-actionbar, settings

I'm actually working on an app where I want to have 2 icons in my top actionbar, and 2 icons in the bottom action bar. To split actionbars, I put

```
<!-- To support below API Level 14 -->
<meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
       android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

this code fragment into my manifest, and it worked. Now I have two actionbars, and I can also change the order of my icons by using the android:orderInCategory flag. But this doesn't work for the settings button, I can change its orderInCategory flag the way I like, it always stays at the bottom right corner. The second problem is, that NONE of my buttons appears in the top bar, all of them are always in the bottom bar. Any tips on how to solve those two things?

Cheers